# Implications of Poincare symmetry: spin and mass

Tags: special-relativity, hilbert-space, symmetry, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

**Is it correct for me to say that the symmetry of a quantum system with respect to the Poincare group leads to the concept of mass and spin?**

The postulates of the special theory of relativity demand that the Poincare group must be a symmetry group of any closed physical system (one postulate says that inertial reference frames are related by Poincare transformations and the other says that the laws of physics are the same in any inertial reference frame).

If we are considering a single free particle then the physical states of the system are represented as state vectors in a Hilbert space (actually as rays). Wigners theorem says that a symmetry transformation of a system is (at least) represented by a unitary operator acting on the Hilbert space. Thus we are lead to classifying the (projective) unitary irreducible representations (UIR's) of the Poincare group (or equivalently, its universal cover).

It is well known that the UIR's of the Poincare group (in $D=4$) are labelled by two numbers; mass and spin (at least in the $m>0$ case). This is the group theoretic origin of the mass and spin of an elementary particle.

It seems to me, that all of this comes about from the special theory of relativity; by demanding Poincare invariance. So is it correct to say that Symmetry considerations lead to concept of mass and spin in a quantum system?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: Oh, well that's surprising... I was half expecting somebody to tell me that I am misinterpreting something... Thanks!

Comment: Actually the numbers are three: there is also the sign of $P^0$ that is Poincaré invariant and one considers physically sensible those representations  with $P^0>0$ among these with $m>0$. The classification of the case $m=0$ is more complicated...

Comment: You'd think after all of these questions I should be past this stuff by now... but the more deeper I try to understand it, the more questions it raises. I guess it just really fascinates me.

Comment: Please mind that questions asking whether you are correct are not really a good fit for the SE model *if you are indeed correct* since "Yes" is too short to even submit as an answer. Please try to ask questions in a way that an answer can actually contain meaningful information.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes, sorry about that.  I can delete the question if  you like (or you can, I don't mind).  I'll try not to pose questions like this again.

Comment: Eh - these questions are not strictly speaking *off-topic* or anything by our current policy, it's just that it's hard to write an answer to them that's not artifically inflated to get over the minimum length. If you just want to check whether you understood something correctly, you could consider trying to ask in [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) first.

Comment: A good suggestion - I'll definitely try that next time. Thanks very much :)